# Installing a Swiss Madison in-wall carrier, installed toilet

Tags: plumbing, framing

I am installing a Swiss Madison in-wall carrier.

The dimensions on the install sheet state that the carrier requires 22 13/16" width between studs.

Isn't the space between 2x4 studs 24" on center actually only 22 1/2"?
I am asking so I place the stud in the correct spot.

[image: In wall toilet installed]

[image: model of carrier]

Comment: Standard stud spacing is either 16" or less common 24" on centre.  22.5" should be the empty space between 24" studs.  The Swiss might have different standards.

Comment: What is "swiss madison in wall carrier"? You might want to provide more details. Maybe even provide the exact make/model of the device and a link to the installation instructions.

Comment: Googling says its a brand of toilet. And no, its not Swiss, but rather New Jerseyian.

Comment: @CherM please be clear in your question ... swiss madison is a brandname, so it is `Swiss Madison` ... furthermore you are not installing the manufacturer, you are installing a product that Swiss Madison makes ... which product are you installing?

Comment: @jsotola - the OP is installing an "in wall carrier" for a Swiss Madison toilet. The "carrier" is for the flush tank & mechanism, which is hidden inside the wall cavity between the studs. The only reason I know this is because I installed one myself about 18 months ago  - otherwise I'd be interpreting that sentence the same way you did.

Comment: Onlly if your 2x4's are still 1.5", which might well not be true anymore. The industry keeps shrinking every nominal size...or else you get to reframe that wall to suit the "hidden" toilet.

Comment: It's great that we can all do some googling and guessing and diving as to what the OP is attempting to accomplish. It would be _much better_ if the person asking for free help were to actually provide the details about what she's doing instead of expecting us read her mind.

Comment: @Ecnerwal "The industry keeps shrinking every nominal size" Ain't that the truth! It particularly concerns me that new 14-guage wire is a noticeably thinner diameter than the 50 year old 14-gauge wire in my house. This is easily noticeable when twisting a new wire in with the old, when grasping the ends in linesman pliers the old wires are held snug while the new is still loose.

Comment: @GlenYates -- are you talking about the actual wire, or the insulation around it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Actual wire.

Comment: Sorry, things got busy here and I fell asleep while looking on my phone. I turned 65 and discovered i wasn't 20 anymore.  Yes it is the brand Swiss Madison in wall carrier. The dimensions stated are 22 13/16 for the carrier. My studs are 16oc. I have to put a stud at 24oc, then remove the old stud. But(yes it is 1.5x3.5) the dimensions for 24oc is 22.5. I wondered if that is too narrow since i am putting in the stud for 24oc. I figure now would be the time to see if anyone knew. Trying to limit lifting, otherwise i'd try it out, i already lift what i shouldn't love the smell of sawdust.

Comment: I don't understand your update. You've already installed the toilet? Then why bother updating the question, just let sleeping dogs lie... If you have a new question about the tiling, then ask a new question.

Comment: Because I was thrilled as it was my first ever big project.  Sorry to bother you sir, I'll stay off the exchange. I'm retired and am doing things I've never done. Again sorry, I was just happy and they helped with their ideas.

Comment: @Cher, this site works differently.  If you revert your question to what it was, then you can post an answer to it, explaining how you solved it.  And that may be more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the space between 2x4 studs 24" on center actually only 22 1/2"?

**YES** the spacing for standard 2x4" (nominal) 1.5x3.5" (actual) studs, the gap between will be 22-1/2".

That answers the question you asked.

---

To answer the question you didn't ask:

If this is *not* a load bearing wall, you could, most likely, get away with sliding this one stud out an extra 3/8". I highly doubt it would be the first stud in the history of home construction to not end up *exactly* on its mark.

If you really don't like that idea, or it is a load bearing wall, frame out the opening for the carrier exactly the same way you'd frame for a window opening with king studs, jack studs, cripples and a header across the top.

Comment: 3/8" ? Even if it was a load bearing wall, what difference would that make!?

Comment: Kinda my point, @GlenYates, but an option for those who are very particular and/or have incredibly picky inspectors.